# 3 dependent Select2 cause endless loop

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

Using select2 to style 3 dependent dropdowns causes much trouble on my project.

Usecase: There are 3 dropdowns: A, B and C. C can be chosen solely, A must have a non-default-value of B and vice-versa.
Doing this without select2 is easy, but using `.select2("val"` instead of plain `.val(` with standard dropdowns causes the issue, that by resetting a dropdown, it causes a "change"-event, even if there was no change in actual value.

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/nmeoosLk/7/

This could be a solution, but is it elegant?
http://jsfiddle.net/8ozv4nr1/

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things involved here that it's useful to know.

First, `.select2("val", xyz)` [is equivalent to](https://github.com/select2/select2/blob/c24293f2ba3d1de3b2dd1421177d3d91b05be887/src/js/select2/core.js#L462-L470) `.val(xyz).trigger("change")`. The reason why a `change` event is triggered is for two reasons

- Older versions of Select2 used to trigger the `change` event, so we gave an easy-upgrade path.
- Other components on the page should be listening to the `change` event to know when the value of the `<select>` changes, so it makes sense to trigger it.

Second, Select2 can only know if the underlying value of the `<select>` changes if you trigger the `change` event.

So when you combine these two issues together, it starts to explain why Select2 doesn't act as you would expect when you set the new value within a `change` event.

---

You can get around the cyclic `change` events by using the `select2:select` event to determine when a new selection is made, instead of the `change` event.

https://jsfiddle.net/nmeoosLk/8/

This is locking you into using Select2-specific events, but it's your best alternative if you don't want to always check if the value changed. I personally would recommend not triggering the `change` event if the value didn't change, as the small amount of code will better help other components understand what is happening on the page.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Select2 v4, here is a generic code snippet to make cascading / dependent dropdown. And the dependency can be chained.

Using this module, options of a select2 list box will be **loaded/refreshed by ajax** based on selection of another select2 list box.

https://gist.github.com/ajaxray/187e7c9a00666a7ffff52a8a69b8bf31

For example -

```
new Select2Cascade($('#country'), $('#province'), 'path/to/geocode', {type:"province", parent_id: ''});
new Select2Cascade($('#province'), $('#district'), 'path/to/geocode', {type:"district", parent_id: ''});
```

Selected value of parent select2 listbox will be set to the `parent_id` of the data object before ajax call.